# mysql: Change the column name to the value of data

Tags: mysql, sql

I would like to create another table with column name is one of the value of the table. I want column name changes dynamically.

For example,

```
+-----------------+------------+------------+--------------+---------------+
| name            | continent  | area       | population   | gdp           |
+-----------------+------------+------------+--------------+---------------+
| Afghanistan     | Asia       | 652230     | 25500100     | 20343000      |
| Albania         | Europe     | 28748      | 2831741      | 12960000      |
| Algeria         | Africa     | 2381741    | 37100000     | 188681000     |
+-----------------+------------+------------+--------------+---------------+

+-------------+
| Asia        |
+-------------+
| Afghanistan |
+-------------+

+-------------+
| Europe      |
+-------------+
| Albania     |
+-------------+

+-------------+
| Africa      |
+-------------+
| Algeria     |
+-------------+
```

Is this possible in mysql? I don't know how to start this one.

Comment: What is your expected output?  It looks like three separate tables/result sets.

Comment: Your question raises a lot of issues: Is your `continent` field tied to another table (`continents`), which limits entries for this field to valid continents? It should be. What if the name of a continent changes (e.g. from "N America" to "North America")? Dynamically creating tables based on the values of a field seems like a bad idea: What problem are you ultimately trying to solve? There may be a better (and easier) way to go about solving it.

Answer (score 0):

I can provide an algorithm

1. Create a `trigger` after `insert` to the table
2. check the table exists with the name of continent using below mysql query

`SELECT * FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_schema = 'yourdb' 
 AND table_name = 'continentName' LIMIT 1;`

3. if exists, `insert` into that table with the new value of name
4. else `create` table with continent and `insert` the value

Hope it helps